JMeter Extracting Results
Test Setup
Test Steps
Hello! Is there a way to get the specific transactions per thread that JMeter does?
For example I want to see the following:
File Upload Transaction #1
Get Extracted Data Transaction #1
File Upload Transaction #2
Get Extracted Data Transaction #2
Etc.
I want to check the matching per request, currently the report looks like this
Report
Im still looking for a way around

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You can add __threadNum() function as a postfix to your Sampler label, this way for first virtual user it will be 1, for second 2, etc.

If you have > 1 loop in Thread Group and want to distinguish results coming from different loop you can also add []3 to identify the current loop number as well:
${__groovy(vars.getIteration(),)}

More information on JMeter Functions concept: Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction

Will try this thanks! But for example I have File Upload request and Get Extract Data request, how can i know that this file upload request, matches the get extract data request if there are different loops? You can see my test script in the main post
